# how to embed mongo db documents in php

Tags: php, mongodb, database, nosql

I'm using PHP Mongo driver. Considering these one-to-one relationship, how can I dynamically embed street inside the first document?

```
{ _id: "joe", name: "Joe Bookreader" }

{ patron_id: "joe", street: "123 Fake Street", city: "Faketon", state: "MA" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed subdocuments through a simple update query, which grabs the item with given _id and sets the street field with the document value :

```
$first_collection->update(['_id'=>'joe'],['$set' => ['street' => ['name'=>"123 Fake Street", 'city': "Faketon", 'state': "MA"]]]);
```